# want to remove "0" at index 0 in a list but not 10,20,30..... C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace

my code
...

```
List<int> a = new List<int>();
List<int> b = new List<int>();
```

...

some boxes for input

...

```
var match = a.Intersect(b);
string output = string.Join(",", match);
foreach (var x in output)
{
     label.Text += Regex.Replace(Convert.ToString(x), "[0]", "");
}
```

but this deletes all 0's 
if I enter 0, 10, 100
I only wanna delete the first 0 (index0 as List is sorted) but I can't make an expression saying that it should remove index0 all the time, because i depends on, if the users enter a 0... so it should look for a 0 at first index and (only) if its there... remove it.

I can't wrap my head around this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show example data?..

Comment: Why don't you use directly `match`? What is the reason to convert them to string and then trying to parse them?

Comment: Your loop iterates the characters within the `output`-string which is fairly sure not what you want. However why don´t you simply delete the very first element fom your list using `List<T>.RemoveAt()`

Comment: Do you want to remove leading zeros from users input?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - though I didn't think about leading zeros that can't happen because he intersects lists of `int`

Comment: @HimBromBeere I dont remove the first elemet because I'm not sure that is a 0

I put in zero's when a box is left empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why you need regex and the loop over the chars. Here are 3 ways of doing so:

```
List<int> a = new List<int> { 0, 10, 20, 5 };
List<int> b = new List<int> { 0, 10, 20 };

//Option 1 - .Remove() on one of the lists
a.Remove(0);
var matches = a.Intersect(b);

//Option 2 - .Remove() on intersection
var matches = a.Intersect(b).ToList();
matches.Remove(0);

//Option 3 - .Where()
var matches = a.Where(item => item != 0)
               .Intersect(b);

var text = string.Join(",", matches); //For both ways: 10,20
```

Comment: Thank you SO much... I went for 
     var matches = a.Intersect(b).ToList();
     matches.Remove(0);

and it worked perfectly!